# "Ads not by this site" displayed by ads injected into certain web pages

Tags: windows, spyware, adware

I'm having ads injected into random pages in Firefox, such as Youtube, Wikipedia and Facebook. I know Wikipedia doesn't serve ads, so this must be some kind of adware. Below the ad appears the text "Ads not by this site." Does anyone know exactly what this is? Google isn't turning anything up. I'm currently running a spyware scan, and it's not turning anything up. For reference, here's a screencap.

[image]

Comment: What extensions do you have? What recently changed on your system?

Comment: That was stupid. I looked through the extensions and found some garbage I don't remember installing. I got rid of it and everything's fine. It was the Codec-C extension. If you reformat your comment as an answer, I'll up-vote and accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was also having these ads, and i remembered that two days ago i had installed a Codec-V it was needed to view a video online. and after removing(uninstall) that Codec-V from computer. The ads has also stopped showing right away.

try removing Codec-V program.

Comment: You do understand that "Codec-V" wasn't require to view the video right?  That screams spyware.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine it was a Vid-Saver Chrome and IE add-on, after removing(uninstalling) them both it was all fine.

Comment: So basically: uninstall any plugins or toolbars of which you don't know if they do nasty stuff. You're better off without them

Comment: Different Chrome extension on my machine - one called "BCool"

Comment: "Fast save" extension in my Chrome

Answer (score 2):

After reading and repeatedly coming across mentions of Codec V, I remembered I recently had installed it onto my computer when I was prompted that I needed it to stream videos on a particular website.

So I found it on my computer and uninstalled it and the problem was solved, although in my case it was [Codec M](http://codecm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen on Google Chrome. In my case I found and I uninstalled the extension named "I want this" which had not been there previous and that stopped the ads.